# Trying to get a specific element from an array column in SharePoint get items

Tags: automation, power-automate

So I am a PA beginner and I am trying to generate an csv report to send out in weekly emails from a SharePoint view and I have noticed that one of my columns in that report is not generating data the right data. Come to find out this column is an array (I think) and I am having trouble getting the "Value" value from that array pulled over into the csv file. So this data is tickets that are being assigned to work and each ticket has a "ticket challenge" along with it but not all will have a challenge in which case it will be blank.

This is what I am working with. I am pulling from a Sharepoint list within a specific view  and then selecting the columns I want

[Columns being pulled in for "Select" function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSDEI.png)

and the one giving me the issues is the "Sprint Ticket Challenge" which is names like this:

**@{item()?['Sprint_x0020_Ticket_x0020_Challe']}** when hovered over.

the output for that Select is this:

[Output of the "Select" query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N3hm.png)

I then just take the output and send it to a CSV table

[Take output to CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUnl2.png)

and my file ends up looking like this but I would like to get only what is after the "Value:" so "Pre-requisite incomplete........"

[CSV File with the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJTy9.png)

I have tapped out my knowledge and google for this issue and hoping someone on here has an idea.

-Sean

The above was the flow that I tried. I got the csv report but I just need the output in the column in question to be the "Values".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the Get Items output to xml and use xpath to retrieve the Sprint Ticket Challenge multi-choice values.

Have a look at this thread where GrantJenkins shared a nice solution approach:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Expression-to-Get-DisplayName-from-SharePoint-People-Picker/m-p/1913160/highlight/true#M210643

1.Convert the Outputs to XML in a Compose

```
xml(json(concat('{"root": { value:', outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'], '}}')))
```

2.Use the below in the From:

```
xpath(outputs('XML'), '//root/value')
```

3.Use the below to retrieve the values of the choice and join them back together as a comma separated string value
*You might need to double check if that field name is the same after the XML conversion though*

```
join(xpath(item(), '//Sprint_x0020_Ticket_x0020_Challe/Value/text()'), ', ')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this information! It looks to address my issue and I will give it a try here today. Now could this XML and xpath option take the place of the "Select" query all together and grab all those column from each entry and not just the Sprint Ticket Challenge field?

Comment: It is both. The xml and xpath is used within the select. The xpath just gives you a bit more option to extract the value labels within the same Select (with a text() function)

Comment: Awesome! I just tried it and with a little tinkering it came out flawless! thanks for the help.